# trying to write foreach in oneline in perl and failed

Tags: perl, syntax, for-loop, foreach, simplify

new to perl, trying to playing around with its syntax a bit, then I got this error message

```
$ perl testP
syntax error at testP line 3, near "$_ ("
Execution of testP aborted due to compilation errors.
```

for:

```
$_=$_+1 foreach $_ (@_);
```

Can anyone tell me what went wrong and how to fix it? thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

foreach variable ( array ) is used in normal notation like:

```
foreach $_ ( @_ ) {
    $_ = $_ + 1;
}
```

But you used the reverse notation, that is operation first, and loop then.

In this case you cannot provide variable name for the loop (which is useless anyway, since you're using default variable $_), and the loop should look:

```
$_ = $_ + 1 foreach @_;
```

Please also note that you can use `for` instead of `foreach`, and if you simply want to increment variable, you can do it with ++ operator, thus making it to:

```
$_++ for @_;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_` will get **each different** value of `@_` on **each iteration** of the **foreach**, and the `++` operator will postincrement the values.

So something like this will work:

```
foreach (@_) {$_++;}
```

Note: `$_++` is equivalent to `$_ = $_ + 1`

`$_` and `@_` are special variables in perl and they have an special behavior, in this case `$_` in the context of a foreach loop takes the *current value* on each iteration.

Special variables are one of the complex and powerful parts of perl. You can get some more information about how they work on the [special vars documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Another thing is you **shouldn't** use a *special variable* as target of the `foreach` as they most probably won't work as expected (see also the [foreach documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops))

Comment: `$_++ for @a` works too in case OP wants to use the alternative syntax.

Comment: I still don't quite understand, why post incrementing the $_ value should not work. why writing like  `foreach (@_) {$_++;}` is different with writing like `$_=$_+1 foreach $_ (@_);`

Comment: Thanks for answering, appreciate it.

Comment: If what is wanted is to get the number of elements into $_, then that will NOT work, because foreach local()izes $_. After the loop, $_ will contain whatever value it had before the loop, and the count will not be accessible...

Comment: @user685275: First, on `foreach` either you specify a variable (like `foreach $myvar (@myarray)`  { /* do whatever with $myvar */}) or you don't specify anything and use the special var $_ (like `foreach (@myarray) { /* do whatever with $_ */}`, on the other hand you have a wrong syntax, the sentence you want to execute (if I understood well `$_=$_+1`) goes after the foreach as I said on the examples. I hope now is more clear.